# How to Generate QR BarCode in RPGLE

Tags: qr-code, rpgle

Can someone help me with a sample RPGLE program for printing QR code
using the BARCODE DDS keyword in IBM iSeries

I had tried the following code, but the spool file converted into PDF was blank.

DDS for Print File

> A          R QREC
> A   FLD1          25A    12 12BARCODE(QRCODE 1 *HRZ +
> A                             X'02' (*WIDTH .05) (*SWIDTH 1.5) +
> A                             (*QRCODE 4 1 *CONVERT(1) +
> A                             *TRIM *AIMSTD(99)))

RPGLE PGM

> FQRCDPF    O    E             Printer
> Fld1 = 'My data';
> Write Qrec;
> *InLr = *On;

Comment: Can you share details about your printer and printer file?

Comment: Maybe [THIS](https://www.mcpressonline.com/forum/forum/programming/rpg/18338-qr-barcode-printing-using-rpg-and-dds-tech-tip) can help you

Answer (score 0):

late but can be useful replace *AIMSTD(99) by *UCCEAN

A ...
A (*QRCODE 4 1 *CONVERT(1) +
A *TRIM *UCCEAN)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Printer file WTQRCODP

```
 * The printer file must be created using DEVTYPE(*AFPDS)        
 * and RPLUNPRT(*NO).                                            
 * The *WIDTH will control the size.                             
 * (*WIDTH 0.12) will make a very large barcode.       
 *  CRTPRTF FILE(yourlib/WTQRCODP)         
 *          SRCFILE(yourlib/Qxxxsrc)       
 *          SRCMBR(WTQRCODP)                
 *          DEVTYPE(*AFPDS)                 
 *          PAGESIZE(29.7 21.0 *UOM)        
 *          OVRFLW(69)                      
 *          UOM(*CM)                        
 *          RPLUNPRT(*NO)     
 * -- open new page                                         
A          R NEWP01P                   TEXT('open new page') 
A                                     1' '                          
A                                      SKIPB(001)                   
 * -- page footer      
A          R BOTP01P                   TEXT('page footer     ') 
A                                     1' '                          
A                                      SKIPB(070)                   
 * -- record QrCode                                                 
A          R RECQR0R                   TEXT('Record QrCode')        
A            QRCODP       250A         BARCODE(32 X'02' +           
A                                           (*WIDTH 0.02))          
A                                      POSITION(&QCASX &QCASY)      
A            QCASX          5S 3P      TEXT('top left: +      
A                                            vertical pos.')      
A            QCASY          5S 3P      TEXT('top left: +      
A                                            horizontal pos.')
```

RPG program WTQRCOD

```
fWTQRCODP  O    E             PRINTER usropn                               
f                                     oflind(*in89)                        
 * -- program status                                              
d PgmStatusDS    SDS                                                       
d  psProgram              1     10                                         
d  psParms               37     39  0                                      
d  psJobNam             244    253                                         
d  psUser               254    263                                         
d  psJobNbr             264    269  0                                      
d  psCurUser            358    367                                         
 *                                                                         
d w_string        s             32                                         
 * Ds QrCode controls                                                    
D FN              DS                                                       
D  FN5                    1      1                                         
D  FN6                    2      2                                  
D  FN7                    3      3                                  
D  FN8                    4      4                                  
D  FN9                    5      5                                  
D  FN10                   6      6                                  
D  FN11                   7      7                                  
D  FN12                   8      8                                  
D  FN13                   9      9                                  
 *                                                                  
c     *entry        plist                                           
c                   parm                    w_string                
 * .. barcode controlo values (meaning)   
 *       FN5  = data is in EBCDIC , and ignore escape sequences     
 *       FN6  = EBCDIC data is code page 500                        
 *       FN7  = "smallest symbol"                                   
 *       FN8  = level L - 7% recovery - x'00'                       
 *              level M - 15% recovery - x'01'                      
 *              level Q - 25% recovery - x'02'                      
 *              level H - 30% recovery - x'03'                      
 *       FN9  = structured append sequence indicator                
 *       FN10 = total number structured append sequences            
 *       FN11 = structured append parity data                       
 *       FN12 = UCC/EAN FNC1 and Industry FNC1 flags          
 *       FN13 = Application Identifier (AI) for Industry FNC1 
 *                                                            
c                   eval      fn5 = x'C0'                     
c                   eval      fn6 = x'01'                     
c                   eval      fn7 = x'00'                     
c                   eval      fn8 = x'02'                     
c                   eval      fn9 = x'00'                     
c                   eval      fn10 = x'00'                    
c                   eval      fn11 = x'00'                    
c                   eval      fn12 = x'00'                    
c                   eval      fn13 = x'00'                    
 * .. string to print (ds FN + string)        
c                   eval      qrcodp = FN + %trim(w_string)   
 * .. set position                   
c                   eval      qcasx  = 2                      
c                   eval      qcasy  = 8                      
 *                                                            
c                   open      WTQRCODP                        
c                   write     newp01P                         
c                   write     botp01p                         
c                   write     recqr0r                         
c                   close     WTQRCODP                         
 *      
c                   exsr      sr_exit     
 * =================                      
c     sr_Exit       begsr                 
 * =================                      
c                   eval      *inLR = *on 
c                   return                
 *                                        
c                   endsr
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).